# Why is readline() so slow for PIPE files?

Tags: python, performance, streaming, bigdata, readline

I am trying to read a huge gzipped csv file and process each line.

I tried 2 different implementations:

It happens that **the usually recommended implementation is 100x slower than the alternative**. Am I wrong or is the implementation of `Popen().stdout` really bad? (it seems to read the file character by character).

```
from time import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# We generate a csv file with 1M lines of 3D coordinates
from random import random
import os

N = 1000000
PATH = 'test'
GZIP_PATH = 'test.gz'

with open(PATH, 'w') as datafile:
    for i in xrange(N):
        datafile.write('{0}, {1}, {2}\n'.format(random(), random(), random()))

try:
    os.remove(GZIP_PATH)
except:
    pass

Popen(['gzip', PATH]).wait()

# We want to process the file line by line

# We start with a textbook implementation

def simple_generator(file):
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        yield line[:-1]
        line = file.readline()

with Popen(['gunzip', '-c', GZIP_PATH], stdout=PIPE).stdout as datafile:
    t = time()
    i = 0
    for line in simple_generator(datafile):
        i+=1 # process the line
    print time()-t
    print i

# We start a lower level implementation

BLOCK_SIZE = 1<<16
def fast_generator(file):
    rem = ''
    block = file.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
    while block:
        lines = block.split('\n')
        lines[0] = rem+lines[0]
        for i in xrange(0,len(lines)-1):
            yield lines[i]
        rem = lines[-1]
        block = file.read(BLOCK_SIZE)

with Popen(['gunzip', '-c', GZIP_PATH], stdout=PIPE).stdout as datafile:
    t = time()
    i = 0
    for line in fast_generator(datafile):
        i+=1 # process the line
    print time()-t
    print i

# Output:
#
# 34.0195429325
# 1000000
# 0.232397794724
# 1000000
#
# The second implementation is 100x faster!
```

Comment: Textbook implementation? I've never seen the use of `file.readline()` recommended for a case like this. The usual idiom is to directly use the file as an iterator, `for line in file`, which performs at basically the same speed as your low level implementation.

Comment: You should probably use the python gzip module instead of Popen:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

Comment: @ngrislain Yes it reads byte by byte because default behaviour is _unbuffered_ as documented for `Popen`.  Set a buffer size and it should be faster.

Comment: @ChristianThieme: No `gzip` module does not allow to deal with very large files as it loads the whole file in memory.

Comment: @LukasGraf: `for line in file` does not work for PIPE files in python 2.5 http://bugs.python.org/issue3907

Comment: @BlackJack: Thank you I didn't see that. It answers my question well.

Comment: @ngraislain: The `gzip` module doesn't load the whole file into memory so it is suitable for decompressing large files while they are read and processed.

Comment: i have to agree with BlackJack, the gzip module works quite well unless you do something crazy like f.readlines(), you can simply iterate over the gzip file object like a normal file object

Comment: @BlackJack, you are right, but somehow it did not work in my case as I was uncompressing the file while downloading it from a server while gunzip -c did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper implementation should be to call `Popen` with `bufsize=-1`

```
with Popen(['gunzip', '-c', GZIP_PATH], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1).stdout as datafile:
    t = time()
    i = 0
    for line in simple_generator(datafile):
        i+=1 # process the line
    print time()-t
    print i
```

I am a but surprised that the default behaviour is `bufsize=0` though.

Comment: This definitely fixed the performance gap but, interestingly, `fast_generator` is still 30-40% faster than `simple_generator` when I run these tests.